# Why my toolbar is not showing Overflow icons?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

My main activity uses a no action bar theme. I use a toolbar instead. Now I have designed a menu file for populating icons to the right of the toolbar. The markup for the menu file is shown below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item 
app:icon="@drawable/undo24" android:id="@+id/action_undo" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always"
/>
<item 
app:icon="@drawable/redo24" android:id="@+id/action_undo" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

I override the oncreateoptionsmenu method and draw the icons on the toolbar with this code

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) {
  
 MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.tool_menu,menu);
 return true;
}
```

I can see that the items have been drawn because I can see the click or touch effect but they are invisible. The vector markup  for the icon drawable is shown below

**redo.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF" android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="24dp">
<path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M18.4,10.6C16.55,8.99 14.15,8 11.5,8c-4.65,0 -8.58,3.03 -9.96,7.22L3.9,16c1.05,-3.19 4.05,-5.5 7.6,-5.5 1.95,0 3.73,0.72 5.12,1.88L13,16h9V7l-3.6,3.6z"/>
</vector>
```

**undo24.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF" android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="24dp">
<path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M12.5,8c-2.65,0 -5.05,0.99 -6.9,2.6L2,7v9h9l-3.62,-3.62c1.39,-1.16 3.16,-1.88 5.12,-1.88 3.54,0 6.55,2.31 7.6,5.5l2.37,-0.78C21.08,11.03 17.15,8 12.5,8z"/>
</vector
```

Why are the icons invisible on the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test on my side, it works on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      <item  android:icon="@drawable/undo" android:title="Done" android:id="@+id/action_do" android:orderInCategory="100"  android:showAsAction="always" />
      <item  android:icon="@drawable/redo" android:title="UnDo" android:id="@+id/action_undo" android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**Note:**

1.please add attribute : `android:showAsAction="always"` for the `Item`(not `app:showAsAction="always"`) and add different `Id` for different `Item` of Menu.

2.please replace `app:icon` with `android:icon"`.

Comment: Testing it in a few